# code for capturing screen using system calls in java

Tags: java, spring

I want to capture screenshot at regular interval of time. As I am beginner I need 
little help to create system calls using java code. I want to run this application 
in background.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
static class Screener extends Thread {
    private static final long INTERVAL = 5000;
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Screener screener = new Screener();
    screener.start();

    //do something...

}
```